# How to use Parallel and sequential execution of bash scripts in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have 3 shell scripts a.sh, b.sh and c.sh. the scripts a.sh and b.sh are to be run parallely and script c.sh should only run if a.sh and b.sh are run successfully ( with exit code 0).

Below is my code. The parallel execution is working fine but sequential execution of c.sh is out of order. It is executing after completion of a.sh and b.sh even if both the scripts are not returning exit codes 0. Below is the code used.

```
#!/bin/sh

A.sh &

B.sh &

wait &&

C.sh
```

How this can be changed to meet my requirement?

Comment: What is the return of the last ID? Is it possible that A.sh or B.sh returned a non-zero value. Have you tried removing the "&&". Then C.sh will always be run

Comment: According to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html#tag_20_153), "If the `wait` utility is invoked with no operands, it shall wait until all process IDs known to the invoking shell have terminated **and exit with a zero exit status**" (my emphasis). Therefore, you need to `wait` for each separately to get the background processes' exit statuses.

Answer (score 2):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ./a.sh & a=$!
    ./b.sh & b=$!
    
    if wait "$a" && wait "$b"; then
      ./c.sh
    fi
```

Hey i did some testing, in my a.sh i had an exit 255, and in my b.sh i had an exit 0, only if both had an exitcode of 0 it executed c.sh.

Comment: You could simplify to just `if wait "$a" && wait "$b"; then`...

Comment: @tripleee yes looks cleaner 

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
.....
wait &&
    if [ -z "the scripts a.sh or any commande u need  " ] 
    then
       #do something
       C.sh
    fi
```

Comment: Should I use wait && in the beginning??

Comment: #!/bin/sh

A.sh &

B.sh &

wait &&
    if [ -z "the scripts a.sh or any commande u need  " ] 
    then
       #do something
       C.sh
    fi

Comment: just replace : C.sh
 with :   if [ -z "the scripts a.sh or any commande u need  " ] 
    then
       #do something
       C.sh
    fi

Comment: If one of the scripts a or b takes longer will c still be run?

Comment: @yassir ait ek aizzi thank you...but, why is the if loop being used there, the purpose?

Comment: @Kendle , c.sh should only run after a.sh nd b.sh are run successfully..with exit code 0